# NameError: uninitialized constant when using Capybara

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara, refinerycms

I'm getting this error when running a test, but it works in the browser! I can't figure it out. It's strange that it complains about line 143 when it is also referenced in line 142!

```
1) Sign Up signs up user
 Failure/Error: click_button 'Sign Up'
 NameError:
   uninitialized constant UserPlugin
 # ./app/decorators/models/refinery/user_decorator.rb:142:in `add_plugin'
 # ./app/controllers/community_members_controller.rb:11:in `create'
 # ./spec/requests/sign_up_spec.rb:18:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

#### Code

```
141  def add_plugin(name)
142    raise ArgumentException, "Plugin should be the name of the plugin not a Plugin object." if name.is_a?(::Refinery::UserPlugin)
143    plugins << ::Refinery::UserPlugin.find_by_name(name)
144  end
```

I've tried `require 'refinery/user_plugin'` at the top of the file, at the top of the _spec; I've tried `Refinery::UserPlugin` and just `UserPlugin`. This statement works from the console: `::Refinery::UserPlugin.find_by_name :refinerycms_blog`

This is the top of the `spec_helper.rb`: http://pastie.org/private/wvwopbzueo6zxmjmzjma

Here is the class in question FYI: https://github.com/refinery/refinerycms/blob/master/authentication/app/models/refinery/user_plugin.rb

Capybara 2.2.1, Rails 3.2.14, RSpec 2.14.1

Comment: Update: This is also happening when trying to create users with controller specs in normal RSpec.